# Add regular not antonymous function to class

Tags: php

I wanted to add functions to class, those functions are in separate file(s), those functions contain ($this).

```
class myClass {
    private $myFunctions=array(); // will contain two keys (title, function_object)
    private $var;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->var = 'Hello world';
    }

    public function add_function($title, $func) {
        $this->myFunctions[$title] = $func;
    }

}

function add($x, $y)    {
    echo $this->var; 
    return $x + $y; 
}

$class = new myClass;
$class->add_function('add', 'add()');

echo $class->add(1,2);
```

my goal is to add regular functions (not anonymous functions) to the class or to assign those function(s) to a var which can be passed to the class!

Can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have to understand the oops concepts here.

$this refers to your current class / object. So all functions inside a class will be able to access $this ( Current Object ).

But the function declared out side of class can not use $this of that object. (Are you clear up to here.)

But anyways nothing is impossible.

You can achieve your goal in at-least 2 ways.

2) You can use trait to implement multiple inheritance.

it will be like this

```
trait commonFunctions
{

    function add($a, $b)
    {
        $this->result = $a + $b;

        return $this;
    }
}

class myClass
{

    use commonFunctions;

    public function myClassFunction()
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

2 ) Or you can follow below code. Source php.net

```
<?php

class A {
    function __construct($val) {
        $this->val = $val;
    }
    function getClosure() {
        //returns closure bound to this object and scope
        return function() { return $this->val; };
    }
}

$ob1 = new A(1);
$ob2 = new A(2);

$cl = $ob1->getClosure();
echo $cl(), "\n";
$cl = $cl->bindTo($ob2);
echo $cl(), "\n";
```

Here __call will be called when undeclared method is being called. So you can dynamically append methods to class by this way.

Of course you can polyfill your object in javascript like way. But keep in mind you need to use Reflection to bind this to closure.

```
<?php

class A {

    private $dynamic_functions=[];

    public function __call($method, $args=[])
    {
        if(isset($this->dynamic_functions[$method]) && $this->dynamic_functions[$method] instanceof \Closure)
        {
            $cl = $this->dynamic_functions[$method]->bindTo($this);

            return call_user_func_array($cl, $args);
        }
        else
        {
            die("Wrong method, Not yet polyfilled.");
        }
    }

    public function __set($property, $value)
    {
        $this->dynamic_functions[$property] = $value;
    }
}

$a = new A;

$a->sum = function($a,$b){

    // var_dump($this); will give you current instance of A

    return $a+$b;
};

echo $a->sum(5, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks @PratikSoni the anonymous functions are not my intention.
using trait is kinda complicate the matter.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but their are limits. When calling undefined methods on an object, PHP checks if there is a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.magic.php) named `__call`:

```
public mixed __call ( string $name , array $arguments )
```

This function then receives the function name, and the list of arguments. For your construction you could use

```
public function __call($name, $args) {
    // invokes the function with all arguments:
    // e.g: function_name($arg[0], $arg[1], ...)
    return call_user_func_array($this->myFunctions[$name], $args);
}
```

There is just one problem, namely you cannot use $this within your anonymous functions. In python this problem got solved by passing the instance as the first argument (which is usually called `self`). We can build something similar by adding the instance to the argument list:

```
public function __call($name, $args) {
    // we add the instance at the beginning of the argument list
    array_unshift($args, $this);
    return call_user_func_array($this->myFunctions[$name], $args);
}
```

Now you could do something like

```
function bork($instance, $a, $b) {
    return $a*$b;
}
$class = new myClass;
$class->add_function('derp', 'bork'); 
$class->add_function('add', function($instance, $x, $y) { 
    echo $instance->var; 
    return $x + $y; 
});

echo $class->derp(1,2);
echo $class->add(35,34534);
```

If you have already some function which does not have `$instance` as a first argument, you could wrap it

```
function my_cool_existing_function($bla) {
   echo $bla.$bla;
}
$class->add_function('super_bork', function($instance, $bla) {
   return my_cool_existing_function($bla);
});
```

Comment: This won't work bro as you wan't be able to bind $this to closure and call it at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "bind" in this context? I pass the instance as an argument since one cannot bind it in PHP

Comment: +1. Yes that's perfect, But using $this won't be possible that's what i said. You may pass an object. You could have passed reference to communicate from closure to current scope.

Comment: Thanks @keksnicoh  an awesome and inspiring trick, I will give it try!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't add a function to a class like this. You can extend your class with other class having this function add(). This way inherited class will have parent's function add().

Comment: Using trait is possible way.